# How to detect what's in the center of the screen with intersection observer

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, intersection-observer

I'm using intersection observer to my single page react app to update the status of my navbar to show where the user is sitting. I have two main problems, the first one is that scrolling down every element gets detected but when I scroll from bottom to top it tends to skip one element, and the main problem that I have is that I can't wrap my head around how to use `rootMargin` and `threshold` to make the intersection observer detection consistent. Right now it tends to set the visible section when the new element merely starts.

My page contains five sections with padding top and bottom. Some sections are bigger than other ones and that makes intersection observer detect as is intersecting the sections pretty inconsistent.

This is how my sections are laid out:

[image]

In this example I would like the visibleLocation to be About, not Why as it occupies a small percentage of the viewport.

[image]

Here is my hook to detect what element is Intersecting:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useLocation = (refs) => {
  const [visibleLocation, setVisibleLocation] = useState("");
  const options = {
    root: document.querySelector(".app"),
    threshold: [0.2, 0.5],
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    refs.forEach((ref) => {
      const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
        const entry = entries[0];
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          setVisibleLocation(entry.target.className);
        }
      });
      observer.observe(ref.current, options);
    });
  }, []);
  return { visibleLocation };
};

export default useLocation;
```

This is how I use it in my navbar:

```
{links.map((link, i) => (
              <li
                className={`navbar-item ${
                  visibleLocation == namesEn[i].toLowerCase() &&
                  navStyle != "nav hide"
                    ? "navbar-item-where"
                    : ""
                }`}
              >
                <Link
                  className="navbar-link"
                  to={link}
                  spy={true}
                  smooth={true}
                  isDynamic={true}
                >
                  {names[i]}
                </Link>
              </li>
            ))}
```

And the nav-item-where element looks like this:

```
.navbar-item-where {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #66CCFF;
}
```

Comment: You've supplied an array for `threshold`, which means [the observer will be called when the target is 20% visible, and again when it is 50% visible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#intersection_observer_options). That's why the "Why" section is showing up; it's about 20% visible, so the observer is called. Sounds like you want something more like a single value like `threshold: 0.7` so that 70% of the section is visible before the menu item is triggered.

Comment: Using `threshold: 0.7` or `threshold: 0.6` makes it better but still fells really inconsistent.

Comment: Not sure how to make it "feel" consistent. It's programmatically exact -- it's doing exactly what you're telling it to do. I'd try with `root: null` also. Hard to tell/debug with the amount of information provided. A [mre] would go a long way.